# Issue on Python Descriptor attribute when called

Tags: python, class, descriptor

I am confused with the code **'self.funcGet'** because it refers to the **'get'** function which is **not bound by the class or instance**. *can anyone explain the strangeness that I saw in this desciptor*

```
class  Desc:
    def __init__(self,funcGet):
        self.funcGet = funcGet                      #funcGet -> get
    def __get__(self,instance,owner):
        return self.funcGet(instance)               #self.funcGet(instance) -> get(instance)
        #return instance.__class__.get(instance)    #same as code above, this is what I caught in mind
class Test:
    def get(self):
        return 'wow'
    prop = Desc(get)


a = Test()
print(a.prop)                                       #This call __get__ in Desc Class
```

the output is

```
wow
```

Comment: It's not a bound method but you provide the instance manually.  I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, could you clarify the question? What did you expect?

Comment: @MSeifert i expect that 'self.funcGet' is 'get'. so when it return self.funcGet(instance) it look like get(instance), without a class. and thanks for your comment. i respect it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line:

```
return self.funcGet(instance)
```

you are just calling 'get' function from Test class (not bound at this step) and returning the result ("wow" string).

By "." access you triggered `__get__` from the descriptior (where binding should take place)

To bind the instance you should use:

```
return self.funcGet.__get__(instance)
```